# Exclude post type from custom taxonomy template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have setup a custom taxonomy called "video_categories" and have set it to two different custom post types - "videos" and "locations".

I am using the template "taxonomy-video_categories.php" to display the posts that have related taxonomys but I would only like to display the post type "videos" and exclude the post type "locations".

Comment: What did you try actually ? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts) to alter the main loop.

Put the following code before `have_posts` call :

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=video' );
```

A proper way for doing this is to hook into `pre_get_posts` :

> query_posts() is the easiest, but not preferred or most efficient, way
>   to alter the default query that WordPress uses to display posts. Use
>   query_posts() to display different posts than those that would
>   normally show up at a specific URL. (The preferred way is hooking into
>   'pre_get_posts' and altering the main query that way using
>   is_main_query)

Comment: What would look like the code inside a `pre_get_posts` hook ? I mean, how do you make to not specify the video post_type to the unrelated queries?